# Network: now it works, now it doesn't! Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, networking, services

I was using XAMPP and uninstall-ed it, and some errors appeared. "Mercury not working" and stuff like that, so I decided to deactivate those services. I may had done something wrong, cus my network is not constant. I do a 'ping -t www.google.com' to keep track if i can or not connect no any server. Its normal for 5 minutes and then 2 minutes of "Ping timout".
Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the settings for your network card.  I had intermittent problems and found out that Vista was turning off my network interface to save power.  Unchecking the box that allowed it to do this solved the problem.  See my answer to [the question](https://superuser.com/questions/47393/what-could-cause-a-network-interface-to-intermittently-drop) for details.

Comment: So far, so good! I had no idea that vista would disable the wireless adapter to save energy. Thats just stupid.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you restore your system to its state as before you deactivated these services (but after the uninstall), then do it again, but one-by-one to find out the service that shouldn't be disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would i restore in windows vista? I never got the hand of this OS.

Comment: Go to Control Panel / System (or just press Win-Pause), then System Protection, click the button System Restore, then Next, then choose by date. You may need to click on "Show older than 5 days".